# Single application for MacOSX 10.7, 10.6 and 10.5

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, osx-leopard

My client wants an application, that uses 10.7 specific features (eg. it's compiled with 10.7 SDK to support resume, no specific code changes are needed for this), but it's needed, that the same application runs on 10.5 and 10.6. This application shall get into App Store.
Any ideas?

Comment: As nobody got any suggestion, I'll write what we did: we compiled the 2 bundles. Got the 2 binaries into the same bundle, and created a launcher, that chooses which binary to launch depending on the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could set Deployment target to 10.5 and all will be fine. But in this case specific Lion features will be not working in the lowest versions of osx. Also you should not call selectors thats not exist in lowest versions. In this case you should wrap osx 10.7 selectors into responsToSelector: statement.